# Script keeps executing causing timeout issues

Tags: php

I actually don't have a problem/error as such, i have developed a small application that triggers a PHP script, using the cpanel xmlapi it creates an addon domain, the code is very basic:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['a'])) 
{
  // include the xml class
  include('xmlapi.php');    
  // try...
  try {
      // credentials username,password,host(ip)
      $cpanelU = $_GET['cpu'];
      $cpanelP = $_GET['cpp'];
      $cpanelH = $_GET['cph'];
      $cpanelD = $_GET['cpd'];
      // execute the addondomain query
      $xmlapi = new xmlapi($cpanelH);
      $xmlapi->password_auth($cpanelU,$cpanelP);
      $xmlapi->set_debug(1);
      $xmlapi->set_port(2083);
      $domainRegistration = $xmlapi->api2_query($cpanelU, "AddonDomain", "addaddondomain", array(newdomain=>$cpanelD, dir=>"public_html/".$cpanelD, subdomain=>$cpanelD, pass=>$cpanelP));  
      print_r($domainRegistration);
      echo $domainRegistration;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
  }
  //var_dump($_GET);
} else {
    header("Location: http://www.site.info/");  
}
  exit(); 
?>
```

Once the script activates it works perfectly creating an addon domain, the problem is the script keeps running and causing timeout issues, even though the job is being done it's not stopping, i'm not sure the best way to go in terms of solving this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe add an `exit();`  before the closing PHP tag ?

Comment: Hi Duane, tried that just now still the same, i have never come accross this before lol

Comment: Even though that didn't help, I still suggest leaving it in and updating the code in your question to include it. I think we both know, it certainly can not make matters worse, and will prevent others from suggesting it.